# swift whole screen View

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I try to add whole blackView on keyWindow when tap button, I used the old method below

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackView.frame = keyWindow.frame
            keyWindow.addSubview(blackView)
        }
```

but it can't work now, how do I do? can cover whole screen
[How to make the blackView can cover the statusBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VAuG.png)

Comment: the question is WHERE are you adding this code ...

Comment: after Button Tapped, and show the blackView, but statusBar is always there, like the picture

Comment: if you print(keyWindow.frame) - what are the values you see for y ? I remember reading somewhere that sometimes the window will not always be the size the of the screen.

Comment: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) Its the frame of iphone7, I open a new project, Its ok to get the whole screen, maybe some bug in my code, I will try , thank you Shawn Frank

Comment: I solve this problem, because I simulate NavgationController to push a new ViewContoller, but I didn't use navigationContoller. I add a TopView, and let StatusBarView.backgroundColor to the Color of TopView. so, the StatusBar is always there. now, everything is okay, thank you for you spent your time to answer my question , I am so stupid, sorry